# What are the vector erase and insert methods doing under the hood?

Tags: c++, vector

On a very low level, what exactly are these methods doing?

Because I have noticed some weird behaviour, for example, if I have a vector with the elements...

```
2, 4, 6, 8
```

And I say `myVector.erase(myVector.begin() + 1);`, it gives me....

```
2, 6, 8, 8
```

However, If I then say `myVector.insert(myVector.begin + 1, 3);`, it gives me...

```
2, 3, 6, 8
```

I don't get any repeated elements. How are these methods implemented under the hood?

EDIT: Code.

```
vector<int> v;

v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(6);
v.push_back(8);

v.erase(v.begin() + 1);

cout << v[0] << v[1] << v[2] << v[3];
```

This gives me `2688`

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It isn't weird behaviour when you're violating the contract and printing out-of-bounds elements (presumably, since you have four elements printed for a three-element vector).

Comment: You are not printing your vector correctly.

Comment: @Ogen You need to post your code, because you're doing something wrong when you're printing out 4 elements after you have erased one of them.

Comment: @chris I would have thought if I were printing out of bounds elements I should be getting out of bounds exceptions thats why I consider it weird.

Comment: @Ogen, C++ doesn't hold your hand and give you a clear error every time you do something wrong. That would require making all of the people who don't do that pay for something they don't use. If you want that to happen, you can enable your standard library's "debug mode" or use a sanitizer.

Comment: @chris It's literally one if statement. It just checks if the index is greater than the vector's size. I don't consider that hand holding; it's common decency I say!

Comment: @Ogen An if statement is expensive. If you want bounds checking, use the `at()` member function instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially the vector has 4 elements

```
2, 4, 6, 8
```

So its size is equal to 4 and the capacity (according to the example) also is equal to 4.

After statement

```
myVector.erase(myVector.begin() + 1);
```

all elements that are after the erased element 4 are moved left.

```
2, 6, 8, 8
```

But now the size is equal to 3 but the capacity still equal to 4. The vector does not free the unused memory in the allocated extent.

Again after statement

```
myVector.insert(myVector.begin + 1, 3);
```

all elements are moved right to free the inserted poistion

```
2, 3, 6, 8
```

Now the size is equal to 4 and the capacity is as usual equal to 4.

You can imagine the process the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    size_t size = 4;
    size_t capacity = 4;

    std::cout << "size = " << size << ", capacity = " << capacity << std::endl;
    std::cout << "current state of the array: ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The memory occupied by the array: ";
    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    //  removing the element with index 1
    size_t i = 1;

    for ( ; i + 1 < size; i++ ) a[i] = a[i+1];
    --size;

    std::cout << "\nsize = " << size << ", capacity = " << capacity << std::endl;
    std::cout << "current state of the array: ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The memory occupied by the array: ";
    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    //  inserting the element with index 1 and value 3
    i = 1;
    int value = 3;
    size_t j = size;
    for ( ; j != i; j-- ) a[j] = a[j-1];
    a[j] = value;
    ++size;

    std::cout << "\nsize = " << size << ", capacity = " << capacity << std::endl;
    std::cout << "current state of the array: ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The memory occupied by the array: ";
    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
size = 4, capacity = 4
current state of the array: 2 4 6 8 
The memory occupied by the array: 2 4 6 8 

size = 3, capacity = 4
current state of the array: 2 6 8 
The memory occupied by the array: 2 6 8 8 

size = 4, capacity = 4
current state of the array: 2 3 6 8 
The memory occupied by the array: 2 3 6 8
```

Comment: So erase doesn't actually **erase** anything, it simply pushes leading elements back one?

Comment: @Ogen you should use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: @Ogen Maybe. Maybe not. It's probably not purposely *overwriting* the "erased" element, but it does change the vector's size (possibly re-allocating the underlying storage). In any case, your code invokes undefined behavior by trying to access a non-existent element.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant So what is the point of a vector having a capacity if you can't access elements that are within the capacity but not within the size?

Comment: @Miki, All that needs erasing is a single element at a specific location, so `std::remove` isn't necessary. It's usually when using only `std::remove` that you'll want to also use `erase`.

Comment: @Ogen, So it can guarantee amortized constant time for insertions and deletions at the end. It's a lot more practical *not* reallocating and copying/moving everything over on every insertion and deletion.

Comment: @chris OH!, ofcourse, that was a really stupid question

Comment: @Ogen Memory reallocation is am expensive operation. So the vector does not reallocte the whole extent of the memory when an element in this extent is erased. It simply moves existent elements one position left that to occupy the freed position.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You said that erase *possibly re-allocates the underlying storage* but I read in this link (http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) that *Erasing elements never triggers a reallocation, nor does it influence the capacity()*.

Comment: @Ogen I may have been wrong about the reallocation part; however, whether or not the vector reallocates is irrelevant, since its size will be decreased, and accessing an element at indices >= `size()` is undefined behavior either way.